# How to Create a Thumbnail of mp3 file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, thumbnails

Hey Recently I am working on Music Player project and I have cover mostly things but I am Stucked how to create the mp3 files thumbnails.I have tried this

```
  final int THUMBSIZE = 64 ;
  File file= new File(songpathll);
  Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail(file, new Size(100,100),null);
```

this is showing error

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createAudioThumbnail(Ljava/io/File;Landroid/util/Size;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap; in class Landroid/media/ThumbnailUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.ThumbnailUtils' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

Comment: [`createAudioThumbnail`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils#createAudioThumbnail(java.io.File,%20android.util.Size,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) was added in API Level 29 (i.e. Android 10). What's the target SDK level of your project?

Comment: 28 That's fine .

Comment: What do you mean by "that's fine"? You can't use API 29 methods if your target SDK level is 28.

Comment: i also tried the method below api level 29 thats also giving same error

Comment: If you are trying to add artwork to an MP3 file, we might be better off looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadata.Builder

Comment: i checked out there but didnot understand anything

Comment: Just to clarify what you are trying to achieve: Do you have an MP3 file that you are trying to extract the image metadata from?
Or are you trying to add image metadata to an MP3 file?

Comment: i want to rectreive already present image in the mp3 file

Answer (score 0):

I would check which version of Android you are targeting in your project.

That override for `createAudioThumbnail()` was added in API v29. [Check here for the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils#createAudioThumbnail(java.io.File,%20android.util.Size,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)).

If you are targeting a lower API version you might need to do something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail(file, Size(THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE), null)
} else {
    // Use the deprecated version for older devices.
    ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail(filepath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)
}
```

Comment: I have set my minimum sdk version to 22 so that no error occurs and my target level is 28 .thats usually fine.

Comment: OK, so it looks like for your use case you can use this version of createAudioThumbnail: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils#createAudioThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: According to the docs, **both** overrides where added in 29 (and one was deprecated in 29 as well, weirdly enough).

Comment: Well that is intriguing. I'm wondering if the most suitable thing then is to just use the `ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail` function then.

Comment: i will try ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail and update you if it Works